# Redux Dev Tools Chrome Extension Immutable.js Causes Error

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js, redux-devtools

Currently, my redux setup (which utilizes Immutable.js for its state) functions completely as desired. However, the redux dev tools extension outputs the following error whenever the is opened:

> An error occurred in the reducer
>   TypeError: n.withMutations is not a function

For context, I'm using [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) for its combine reducers function to, well, combine my react-router-redux reducer:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';

const initialState = fromJS({
  locationBeforeTransitions: null,
});

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    return state.merge({
      locationBeforeTransitions: action.payload,
    });
  }
  return state;
};
```

and my business logic reducers.

UPDATE: Building the production bundle w/ webpack, testing the app in production mode (in a docker container), and testing the app again in development mode (on the local machine w/o docker) seems to have solved the problem? Odd...

Comment: Is this issue resolved by the below answer? Could you update the status or accept the answer if it was sufficient

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `react-router-redux`, no need to implement the reducer your own,
just import the routerReducer as key routing (important) from `react-router-redux` as below and combine with other reducers,

```
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
// Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)

//To Sync navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
        <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('mount')
)
```

Hope this is what you are trying to implement